# ons navigator title bar show me extra height on ios devices

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

i am using ons-navigator
When i test it on iphone it looks like
[iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC6tB.jpg)

and when i test it on android devices it looks like 
[android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWVEC.png)

Comment: Here is my HTML code
`<ons-template id="webview.html" main-page="webview.html" >
  <ons-navigator animation="slide" var="appLogin">
      <ons-page modifier="full_bg" ng-controller="WebViewCtrl">

Comment: I am using ons-navigator for navigate different pages

Answer (score 0):

There is some padding added to the top of the page when running on iOS since the status bar is part of the app.

To disable this behavior you can run

```
ons.disableAutoStatusBarFill()
```

After loading Onsen UI. However, in most cases you want to have the padding in the status bar.